# How to have multiple options on paypal checkout page or even on its own page

Tags: html, paypal, payment-gateway

My question pertains to having multiple options on the checkout page for donations.

Say a non-profit has multiple programs. And it wants to give its users options to donate to different programs, and different amounts, if the users want to in **one go**.

How do I implement that?

Here's an example of what I tried, but no dice. All I get upon clicking on Paypal's donate button is the last one, ie, "Awesome General Fund". It doesn't even show the other options.

```
<input type="hidden" name="business"
    value="donations@kcparkfriends.org">

<!-- Specify a Donate button. -->
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">

<!-- Specify details about the contribution -->
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Friends of the Park">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="Fall Cleanup Campaign">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">

<!-- Specify details about the contribution -->
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="General Fund"> 
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="General Fund">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">

<!-- Specify details about the contribution -->
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Different General Fund"> 
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="Different General Fund">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">

<!-- Specify details about the contribution -->
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Awesome General Fund"> 
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="Awesome General Fund">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">


<!-- Display the payment button. -->
<input type="image" name="submit" border="0"
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donate_LG.gif"
alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
<img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1"
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have the same "name" for many inputs. Most probably PayPal will only consider either the first one or the last one. What you need is a combo box. Something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="business"     value="donations@kcparkfriends.org">

<!-- Specify a Donate button. -->
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">

<!-- Specify details about the contribution -->
<select name="item_name">
    <option>Friends of the Park</option>
    <option>General Fund</option>
    <option>Different General Fund</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">

<!-- Display the payment button. -->
<input type="image" name="submit" border="0"
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donate_LG.gif"
alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
<img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1"     src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >

(...)
```

Comment: Also, you can always have 3 different buttons in your site and let the user choose among them.

Comment: hey thanks. Yeah, I've discovered that you cannot have the same name. I've actually tried `item_number_1`, `item_number_2`, etc, to no avail. And yeah, I know I can offer three different buttons. The issue isn't that. The issue is allowing the user to be able to choose multiple programs in one go, and inputting different amount for each program should they choose to do so. That's what I'm struggling to achieve ... if it is possible.

Comment: It is possible, but you will need some Javascript in order to change the value of some "input"s when the user selects from the combo box a different product.

In general, the problem is not related to PayPal.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple posibility:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Select a new car from the list.</p>

<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="1">product1
  <option value="2">product2
  <option value="3">product3
</select>


<div id="pay1">paypal button code for product 1</div>
<div id="pay2" style="visibility :hidden">paypal button code for product     2</div>
<div id="pay3" style="visibility :hidden">paypal button code for product 3</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var selectedProduct = document.getElementById('mySelect').value;

    if(selectedProduct == 1)
    {
        document.getElementById("pay1").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("pay2").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("pay3").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    else if(selectedProduct == 2)
    {
        document.getElementById("pay1").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("pay2").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("pay3").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    else if(selectedProduct == 3)
    {
        document.getElementById("pay1").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("pay2").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("pay3").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In this solution 1 button is shown and others hidden when the selection changes.

Even another solution:
Similar to the code above, using javascript you can change the value of any input of your form when selection changes.

In any case, your questions is more related to HTML and JS basics rather than PayPal.